# Osherove's naming convention for negative unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, refactoring, naming-conventions

I'm trying to decide on a naming convention for unit tests. I like the one recommended by Roy Osherove:

> [MethodName_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior]

http://osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/naming-standards-for-unit-tests.html

I'm not sure about this standard for the negative tests where we are testing if the application is handling wrong behavior correctly by throwing an exception.

So the ExpectedBehavior would in this case always be "CorrectExceptionThrown". Would it still make sense to write the ExpectedBehavior for each negative unit test or is it ok to make it optional?

There are pros and cons. On one side it's always the same for negative tests so it would be redundant to write it every time, it makes the unit test method name long. It's also a risk that the expected behavior will not be added for unit test where it's necessary, if we make it optional. I also think that it's better to keep it consistent in the entire project so apply it the same way everywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure it can be called "redundant" just because it is repetitive. It says something about the test in each case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing redundant in specifying what exception is thrown as operation result. This actually fits perfectly into Roy's naming convention, given:

```
SomeMethod_ExpectionalState_ThrowsInvalidOperationException
SomeMethod_ExceptionalState_ThrowsArgumentNullException
```

You get an important information about your code - type of exception thrown. However, when you have classical happy path test usefulness of some parts of name is subjective. Consider:

```
SomeMethod_DependencyReturnsCorrectResult_ReturnsResult
SomeMethod_WhenNothingSpecialHappens_ReturnsResult
SomeMethod_EverythingElseWorked_WorksToo
```

What information do such names carry? Rather little. `ReturnsResult` essentially means it works. `NothingSpecialHappens` is also rather vague information. In such cases, dropping part of the name might be justified.

Note however, instead it might be worth considering **changing name** rather than dropping part of it completely (for example, `ReturnsResult` could be replaced with less vague `ReturnsEntityFromDatabase` or `ReturnsSerializedValue`).

Finally, don't follow Roy blindly - treat it as **guidelines**, rather than conventions. Conventions rarely fit for *all possible situations*, and this one is no different.

Answer (score 2):

You could write:

```
[Test]
public void Foo_ExceptionalCaseX1_ExceptionY1Thrown()
{
}

[Test]
public void Foo_ExceptionalCaseX2_ExceptionY2Thrown()
{
}

...
```

If the Exceptional cases are different and the type of exceptions thrown is the same, than there is no redundancy (even if the suffix is the same).
It is no different than writing these two tests:

```
[Test]
public void Foo_SomeCaseX1_42Returned()
{
}

[Test]
public void Foo_SomeCaseX2_42Returned()
{
}

...
```

What can you do - 42 is returned in two cases and that's reality - same for exceptions.

And one more thing: when one reads through a list of tests they might look (almost) the same, but when one of them will fail one day, the lucky developer would be able to know right away what was the expected behavior. Every test should stand for itself.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a situation when a single unit test fails. Then you get a message from CI like that:

```
Failed unit tests:

MethodName_NegativeTestParams1_CorrectExceptionThrown
```

And no other context. And you *see* the problem (incorrect exception was thrown). If you make this optional or try to shorten your method name, you may end up with

```
Failed unit tests:

MethodName_NegativeTestParams1
```

without any clues what went wrong, until you look into the test.

In this case, planning for situation when you have no context except list of failed unit tests, you should make method names as detailed as possible, repeating `CorrectExceptionThrown` as many times as needed.

Moreover, `CorrectExceptionThrown` message may be made less general: `ArgumentExceptionThrown` etc. in case you have different exceptions for different tests.

Thus I'd include expected behavior in all cases, although it may sometimes seem like unnecessary repetition.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's true; however, it's just one way to decide naming convention of unit test. If you obviously know the exception throw in this test, I think .NET framework unit testing will provide an easy way like in JUnit.

`@Test (IOException.class)
 public void testIOException() {...}`